# How to detect subclass sprite touch

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I subclass a sprite called newSprite.h / newSprite.m, and I add a sprite in it

```
CCSprite *nsprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mouse.png"];
[self addChild: nsprite];
```

and in gamelayer.m, I add the following code

```
newSprite *newp = [newSprite node];
newp.position = ccp(actualX, actualY);
[self addChild:newp];
[_NSMutableArrayName addObject:newp];
```

when I use following code to detect which sprite i touched

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];

 for (CCSprite *target in _NSMutableArrayName) {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(target.boundingBox, location)) {
        CCLOG(@"yes i am touched");
    }
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work, the sprite can not be detected, so where is the wrong? please help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

    for (CCSprite *target in _NSMutableArrayName) {
        CGSize size = node.contentSize;
        CGRect r = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f,
                              size.width, size.height);
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(r, local)) {
            CCLOG(@"yes i am touched");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated code. Give that a try. You may need to apply the `parentToNode` transform on the `size`, but that should be doing the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to detect touches on sub sprite and giving the bounds of parent sprite.

First, take **nsprite** as class variable in NewSprite to keep its reference when you call it from GameLayer. Then try changing this method like:

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];

  for (CCSprite *target in _NSMutableArrayName) {
    CCSize size = target.nSprite.contentSize;
    CCRect rect = CCRectMake(target.position.x - size.width/2, target.position.y - size.height/2, width, height);

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, location)) {
        CCLOG(@"yes i am touched");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how to "take nsprite as class variable in NewSprite to keep its reference when you call it from GameLayer"? thanks

Comment: I meant in NewSprite.h declare your variable like CCSprite *nSprite;
and its property like @property (readonly) CCSprite *nSprite;

Comment: I just do like that, but it shows error: property 'nSprite' not found on object of type 'CCSprite *'